# android sdk is not recognized as internal or sdk command

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I have downloaded android sdk in android folder directly .I want to run adb shell.
I am using command prompt for that , but there is problem in for android-sdk internal or external path... so tell me how to set path for **andoroid-sdk**

Comment: You're very unlikely to get an answer to this question; can you post exactly what command you are executing and exactly what response you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

As simple as the first link after a Google search:

https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/step-1-setting-development-environment-android-sdk